# How many elements does the Field $Z_{5[x]}/f(x)$ have?

Tags: finite-fields

In class we are learning about finite fields and polynomials in finite fields my professor wrote that

> $Z_{5[x]}/f(x)$ where $f(x)=x^3+x+1$
>
> Here P = 5, n = 3   $|F|=5^3=125$   So F has 125 elements

I'm a bit confused as to how he determined this, could someone provide me with a bit of an explanation?

Comment: my bad I meant $Z_5$

Answer (score 1):

Your field $K$ has characteristic $p$. Then $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ of degree 3. Now choose a basis of $K$ over $\mathbb{Z}_5$,  Note that every element of $K$ is a linear combination of such elements with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_5$. For each coefficient there are 5 choices (elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5$) and so there are $5^{3}$ linear combinations.